# LaTex Error: File '*.sty' not found

Tags: mactex, compilation-error

I just installed Mactex and when I try to compile a PDF, I get errors that it can't find .sty files for a bunch of things. For example, the command '\usepackage{times}' returns the error "LaTex Error: File 'times.sty' not found. I know this is a common question and I have spent a bunch of time reading previous answers, but they are all very technical answers, and I just don't understand them. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you do a custom installation, or the default installation?  What are the contents of `/usr/local/texlive/`?

Comment: In Terminal run the command ` kpsewhich times.sty` and let us know what it returns.Also, how are you compiling your document (front end, Command line)?

Comment: download this in the first place : https://miktex.org/download

Comment: @zeïnlestatisticien I really don't think switching the whole TeX distribution is the best first step, especially MikTeX on Mac...